# FocusOut/Blur when leaving div with elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

There is a fixed div with some links that are shown when user clicks a button.
For accessibility purposes, I want to close this div when it loses keyboard focus, but I can`t find the correct DOM event to handle.

I've tried `blur` and `focusout` events but they are also triggered even when children elements still has focus.

Example:

```js
function openMenu() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
  menu.setAttribute("open", "");
  menu.addEventListener("focusout", handleMenuFocusOut);
  menu.focus();
}
function closeMenu() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
  menu.removeAttribute("open");
}
function handleMenuFocusOut() {
  console.log("Event triggered!");
  menu.removeEventListener("focusout", handleMenuFocusOut);
  closeMenu();
}
```

```css
#menu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
}
#menu[open] {
  display: block;
}
#menu:focus, a:focus {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="openMenu()">Click Me</button>
  <div id="menu" tabindex="0">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

To reproduce the case, click the button and press tab to navigate between links.
The expected behavior is to close div only when focusing outside elements, like the textbox.

Comment: To OP: take a look at my answer, I've edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've completely changed this answer.

You can do this using pure CSS using `focus-within` and `~` (which is used to show the menu when the open-button is focused.

**Take a look at this snippet which uses no JS:**

```css
#menu {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: cyan;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
*:focus { outline: 3px solid #ff0; }
#menu:focus-within, #open-btn:focus ~ #menu {opacity: 1; pointer-events: all;}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="open-btn">Click Me</button>
  <div id="menu" tabindex="0">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the focus keeps going back to the div menu when pressing tab, not allowing the user to navigate through the anchors.

Comment: @SergioJunior take a look at the answer now

Comment: Fantastic! Can you just briefly comment why the use of pointer-events property? I thought this was specific for SVG elements.

Comment: Yes, of course. The pointer-events property means that the element it is set within is completely transparent to the mouse-pointer. So anything within this element is not clickable, draggable, long-pressable etc etc. This is good, because you can still focus it with the tab-button if your mouse is not working and you therefore cannot click the open-button. And obviously `opacity` means that you will not be able to visually see the menu if it or the open-button is not focused. If you want the button to be toggleable, you can use simple JS to focus or blur the button when it is clicked.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and solution. Regards!